# ¿Hay alguna palabra para un autoinvitado?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, definiciones

En un diccionario (mapuche) encontré una palabra que se define así:

> Uno que se convida a sí mismo para una [remolienda](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VuWd0OF).

¿Hay alguna palabra en castellano, más o menos formal, para referirse a una persona así, además de la que pongo en la pregunta: **autoinvitado**, que no sé si existe y que, además, es más general?

Comment: Autoinvitado no existe. Bueno, no es que no exista, es que no está recogida en el DRAE, pero a mi juicio están tardando en incluirla, jaja.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando el [dirae](https://dirae.es/palabras/?q=invitado) (diccionario inverso) me he encontrado con

> [mamarón](http://dle.rae.es/?id=O5pt2bv) (de mamar)
>
> 1. m. *España. poco usado*: Hombre que procura participar de fiestas y agasajos sin estar invitado.

y los verbos/acciones

> [coladera](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9jIhojp) (de colar)
>
> 5. f. coloq. *Cuba y Uruguay*. Acción de entrar sin ser invitado o sin pagar en una fiesta o espectáculo.

Aunque este último aplica un poco menos, ya que la definición implica "entrar si pagar" y no "entrar sin estar invitado" y además define la acción, no al individuo.

> [colear](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9kNRvTn)
>
> 6. prnl. Venezuela. Asistir a una reunión o fiesta sin haber sido invitado.

Por lo que podríamos entender que quien hace la acción de la *coladera* es un *coleador* (y no un *colador* o *colón*).

Tenemos incluso

> [paracaidista](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RpJ85Vi)
>
> 4. m. y f. coloq. C. Rica, Ec., El Salv., Nic., R. Dom., Ur. y Ven. Persona que se presenta en un lugar sin haber sido invitada, o sin estar citada.

Supongo que por símil a la acción de asaltar con paracaídas.

Parece ser que no hay un término "universal" o del español neutral. "Mamarón" es muy rebuscado y usado solo en España, y "coleador" o "paracaidista" no se van a entender por completo en cualquier contexto (especialmente el segundo, cuyos otros significados están mucho más expendidos que el coloquialismo de "persona que se presenta en un lugar sin haber sido invitada".

Comment: Gracias @Diego, había olvidado una parte importante de la pregunta (acabo de incluirla) y era que necesito un término no muy coloquial, por cierto **paracaidista** también se usa en Chile con ese mismo sentido

Answer (score 1):

No hay ningún problema con *autoinvitado*, incluso aunque no venga en la RAE, ya que se puede derivar de *invitado* y el prefijo [*auto-*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4Quv5F7) 'por uno mismo'. Como su significado se deduce sin problemas de dichos elementos compositivos, no es necesaria su inclusión en el diccionario, y suena bastante formal.

En todo caso, a mí la palabra que se me ocurre es la siguiente, aunque su significado es ligeramente diferente (más genérico), y además es de uso coloquial:

> [**gorrón<sup>2</sup>, na**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JMpIREK)
>
> ```
> De gorra.
> ```
>
> 1. adj. coloq. Que tiene por hábito comer, vivir, regalarse o divertirse a costa ajena. Apl. a pers., u. t. c. s.

El problema es que es de uso mayoritario en España, aunque parece que se conoce también en México, Costa Rica y otros países. Si no te sirve, siempre podemos recurrir a expresiones algo más complejas y coloridas, como *se invitó por la cara*:

> **[por la cara](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7NOG7x2#Eyezu8N)**
>
> 1. loc. adv. coloq. Dicho de aspirar a algo o de hacerlo: Con atrevimiento y sin cumplir los requisitos para ello.

Comment: En Argentina se usa "colado" (por autoinvitado)